# How can I achieve the equivalence of RegisterClientScriptBlock using an ActionLink?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am busy trying to write an Html.DatePickerFor helper, but say I want to use a custom date picker that has JavaScript dependencies, how could I expand my CustomActionLink call to, before rendering content offered by the link, ensure that e.g. jQuery and my own scripts, are on the view being rendered.

In a WebForms app, I would use RegisterClientScript, but with an action link it seems quite more complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you have a look into the [ASP.NET Client Dependency Framework](http://clientdependency.codeplex.com/) which takes care of exactly what you want and supports ASP.NET MVC as well.

> **ASP.NET Client Dependency Framework - Overview**
>
> The ClientDependency Framework is designed to affiliate any of your views & controls to CSS and JavaScript files without having to worry about if other views or controls have already been registered with them, making developing web components much easier because each component has it's own dependencies registered for it to function.

Another option could be to use the [MVC Script Dependency Extension](https://bitbucket.org/glav/mvc-script-dependency-extension). I have no personal experience with this library but it sounds promising.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hide the link in your CSS and have a JavaScript function make the link visible.  If you put the function in your $(document).ready() call, you'll be sure jQuery has been loaded (or else it won't execute and the link will remain hidden).

Comment: Yes, thanks, but my point is to create a permanenly reusable tool, so that when another dev invokes `Html.DatePickerFor(..`, he doesn't need to have configured the jQuery refs etc.  Otherwise I would just use a textbox and 'jQuery it up all pretty'.